# View binding for menu files?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-menu, android-viewbinding

Is it possible to use `View Binding` (or `Data Binding`) in menu resources?

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    
    // search using ID - can this be replaced by view binding?
    val searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).actionView as SearchView
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In most cases, view binding replaces `findViewById`.

According to the [documentations](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding):

> View binding is a feature that allows you to more easily write code
> that interacts with views. Once view binding is enabled in a module,
> it generates a binding class for each **XML layout** file present in that module.

Where in menus it uses `findItem()` and not `findViewById()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Specific to [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) with menu items with custom xml views, **not** [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding):

`partial_menu_sample_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="?actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_sample"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_sample"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline_horizontal_center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_vertical_center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`activity_sample.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_sample"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`SampleActivity.kt`

```
class SampleActivity() {

  lateinit var binding: ActivitySampleBinding
  var menuSampleViewBinding: PartialMenuSampleViewBinding? = null

  ...

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    binding = ActivitySampleBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    // make sure to set the toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbarSample)
  }

  ...

  override fun onCreateOptionsMenu() {
      // inflate the menu to show on your toolbar
      // replace with your own menu xml
      binding.toolbarProduct.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_sample)
      
      with(binding.toolbarProduct.menu) {
            findItem(R.id.menu_item_cart)?.actionView?.let {
                menuSampleViewBinding = PartialMenuSampleViewBinding.bind(it)
            }
            // handle other menu items here
      }
  }

  ...

  fun customFunction() {
      // use as needed
      menuSampleViewBinding?.textviewSample?.text = "1"
      menuSampleViewBinding?.root?.setOnClickListeners { /* add what you need */ } 
  }

}
```

Used this in a use case where there's a badge count on the menu item. Works fine.

Comment: This is working perfectly for view Binding. Thanks!

Comment: In this case, does partial_menu_sample_view.xml have to be in the layout dir and NOT the menu dir? Because mine is in /menu/ and does not have a generated file for me to reference via view binding.

Comment: @ZeekAran `partial_menu_sample_view.xml` is a layout res, not a menu res. It's expected to be in a layout directory.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, `dataBinding` is only for layout resources, not menu resources.